# SexMachine install - UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte in position

Tags: python, anaconda

```
(base) C:\Users\sujit>pip install SexMachine
Collecting SexMachine
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/01/cc5b32af2b3658079736bd865019aeb8db04f9c5764eac72185c276
c/SexMachine-0.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-install-wlnebm4x\SexMachine\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
      File "c:\users\sujit\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 835: character maps to <undefined>

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-install-wlnebm4x\SexMachine\
```

I updated setuptools but it is not solving this problem.

Comment: Is SexMachine a thing or are you pulling your audiences legs? Seems it is .... .https://pypi.org/project/SexMachine/

Comment: @PatrickArtner: it is a thing, see https://pypi.org/project/SexMachine/ and https://github.com/ferhatelmas/sexmachine/

Comment: The project is no longer maintained, no updates in 6 years. The project is also **not compatible with Python 3**. This specific error can be solved, but you'll run into others.

Comment: SexMachine hahahah. Got to learn this one, very important for my career

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install is not compatible with Python 3, and reads a non-ASCII readme file in the setup.py file. Your system default codec is incompatible with the UTF-8 data in the file. While you *could* force this issue by setting a `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` environment variable first, you'll run into other issues later on.

You should instead install the [`gender-guesser` project](https://pypi.org/project/gender-guesser/), which uses the same command-line tool to do the exact same work but is Python 3 compatible:

> This is a fork of the `SexMachine` package by [Ferhat Elmas](https://github.com/ferhatelmas). It was created to be able to publish a Python 3 compatible version to PyPI and to be able add some more improvements without bugging the original author.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `pip3 install SexMachine`

If that doesn't work, maybe update PIP using this command: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

After you updated PIP, then try: `pip3 install SexMachine`

Note: for my answer, I used `pip3`. If `pip3` doesn't work, try `pip`.